# Big-O problem, need help

Tags: asymptotics

f(n) = max(n^2, n^1.5 log^16 n)

f(n) should be O(n^2),Omega(n^2), O(n^1.5 log^16 n)， or Omega(n^1.5 log^16 n)?

Can anyone help me with it and explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For n,
f(n1)=n^2
f(n2)=n^3/2
f(n3)=log^16n
so, f(n3)=16nlog(base2)
therefore, we can draw the conclusion:
16nlog(base2)>n^2>n^3/2

Now, as we know omegan(n) gives lower bound for the function,
so, for any function
O(f(n))>Omega(f(n))
so, the two function with omega bound is not going to give you the desired result.

And, for very large values of n n^2>n^3/2>16nlog(base2)
so, as the generalization, f(n) can be denoted as O(n^1.5log^16n)